# C# create an array of controls

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, components

Is it possible to create an array of controls?  Is there a way to get the index of a control if more than one of the controls in the array share the same event handler?

Comment: Please, define components. Maybe a code sample would help.

Comment: for example: I want to have 30 buttons on a form that share the same click event

Comment: The sender parameter of the click event will be the button that generated the click, so getting the index would be `Array.IndexOf(buttonArray, sender)`

Comment: Wouldn't referencing the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace do as it has the means to use a controls array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is certainly possible to do.  Sharing the event handler is fairly easy to do in this case because the `Button` which raised the event is sent as part of the event args.  It will be the `sender` value and can be cast back to a `Button`

Here is some sample code

```
class Form1 : Form {
  private Button[] _buttons;
  public Form1(int count) { 
    _buttons = new Button[count];
    for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
      var b = new Button();
      b.Text = "Button" + i.ToString()
      b.Click += new EventHandler(OnButtonClick);
      _buttons[i] = b;
    }
  }
  private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var whichButton = (Button)sender;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: this solution works for me.  it's exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Based on Kevins comment:

```
foreach(Button b in MyForm.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    b.Click += Button_Click;
}
```

---

```
void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton = sender as Button;
}
```