# PictureBox value in C#

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have a question I'm still a newbie in C#. I have 10 pictureBox in my Form and in a method that I've created I need to change the picture but the pictureBox can change like this:

```
void evaluate(int c, int i) {
if (contador == 2)
{
    if (aux == i + 10 || aux + 10 == i)
    {
    }
    else 
    { 
        pictureBox+aux+.Image.FromFile(@"C:\MyGame Directory\new.jpg"); 
    }
}
```

I need something like this: Concatenate the `pictureBox+myVariable+`

Comment: U lack some declarations in this code - aux. What type is aux and contador. If u use `if {} else { some code }` its better to revert if.

Answer (score 1):

Try an array of PictureBox variables (assuming `aux` is an int). Then reference one with array notation:

```
pictureBoxes[aux].Image.FromFile(@"...");
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all your pictureBox controls in a dictionary with *aux* as the key, assuming aux is a int:

```
Dictionary<int,PictureBox> picBoxes = new Dictionary<int,PictureBox>();

picBoxes[aux].Image.FromFile(@"C:\MyGame Directory\new.jpg");
```

Comment: Based on his code snippet, `aux` is an int, so the Dictionary key is wrong.

Comment: Look where do I have to put the Dictionary line? I'm sorry but I'm still learning.

Comment: Exactly Nik aux is an int. What is yor suggestion?

Comment: The key type has been corrected. I would be putting the dictionary in a class variable and initialise it in the constructor. Where you fill it will depend on your code, however looking at code, you may be able to fill it in the ctor also.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use an array of PictureBox controls and then set the value for each of the contents using an index.

This may help:

[C# create an array of controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168363/c-create-an-array-of-controls)

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to have soo many picture boxes? Instead have 1 and rotate the pics in it based on a timer or some logic.