# How to set the many button text at runtime in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am using Winform. In that i have set 20 buttons and up and down buttons like below. 
These buttons text value is button1 = 1; button 2 =2; ... button20 =20 at starting time. I have done this.

[image]

When I press Down button, the 20 buttons text has changed to 21 to 40; and Up buttons it returns 1 to 20.

```
btn_Down click event

button21.Text = "21";
button22.Text = "22";
...
..
button40.Text = "40";

and btn_Up Click event

btn_Down click event

button1.Text = "1";
button2.Text = "2";
...
..
button20.Text = "20";
```

Is any Simple way to Code this?

Updated -

When I try sll code,.

```
int index = 0;

foreach (var control in this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
 {
     var button = control as Button;
     if (button != null)
     {
        button.Text = String.Format("{0}", index);
        index++;
     }
}
```

I got Below. The Up and Down is also Changed, And The Numbers Order is reverse.

[image]

Please Update Answers.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve because I can't make sense of "But When I press Down button, the 20 buttons text has changed to 21 to 40; and Up buttons it returns 1 to 20."

Comment: I want For(i=1;i<=20;i++)
(button + i).text = i; Like this. How to Simplify the Button1.text = "1" Coding.

Comment: `using System.Linq; form.Controls.OfType<Button>().ForEach(b => b.Text = "...");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If buttons are arranged in the order from 1 to 20 you do not need extracting number from a button name, just use autoincrement index variable:

```
int index = 0;
// either form.Controls or this.Controls dedepnds on where you put this code
foreach (var control in form.Controls)
{
   var button = control as Button;
   if (button != null)
   {
      button.Text = String.Format("Button #{0}", index);     
      index++;
   }      
}
```

**EDIT: Try it out, have nopt checked since have no environment setup in hand**

To avoid affecting Up/Down buttons mark it by special tag value like Tag="ControlButton"

```
using System.Linq;
var buttons = this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls
                                    .OfType<Button>()
                                    .Where(b => b.Tag != "ControlButton");
int index = buttons.Count();
foreach (var button in buttons)
{
    button.Text = String.Format("Button #{0}", index);     
    index--;
}
```

Comment: Please See my dated Questions.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to find an easy way to set the Text property of those 20 button controls to avoid having to set them one by one?

In that case you could iterate over the form's controls and check if it is a button.

For example:

```
foreach(var control in base.Controls)
{
    if (control is Button)
    {
        var button = (Button) control;
        button.Text = ExtractNumber(button.Name);
    }
}
```

More information about iterating the controls can be found here:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/control

The ExtractNumber(...) method extract the number from the button's Name property.

```
private string ExtractNumber(string value)
{
    var number = Regex.Match(value, @"\d+").Value;
    return number;
}
```

Comment: each time if through false. So ExtractNumber Functions not execute. How I solve this.

Comment: Thanks  and Sorry I am Placed Buttons in tableLayoutPanel1 So It gives False Value. Now I got The Answer. But Up and Down Buttons Also Affected.

Comment: You could add a container control (e.g. Panel) to the tableLayoutPanel and place the Up / Down button inside of them. Then they would be skipped during the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you: [C# create an array of controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168363/c-sharp-create-an-array-of-controls)

You could create an array of buttons and assign the button text like:

```
int i = start_value //e.g. 0 or 20 or 40...
foreach (button b in buttons)
{
    b.Text = i.ToString();
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to setup an array of Button objects in your form. Each element in the array would be one of your buttons. 
Then you can later iterate through the buttons using a simple for-loop.

Something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<buttons.Length; i++)
{
   buttons[i].Text = (i+1).ToString();
}
```

But what are you trying to do? There is probably a more efficient solution to your problem.

Comment: What is buttons refers System.Windows.Forms.button Not have the Length Proprity. and it through error Error 1 The name 'buttons' does not exist in the current context. How i Solve this?

Comment: The code is just a sample. You will have to define an array (I suggest you name it "buttons") with the correct length. You will also have to fill it with references to the buttons in your form. You can do this in the Form_Load event.