# Fill an array with a loop

Tags: c#

I want to get a shorter code than now but I don't know how.

What I do now is like the code below.

```
arrPictureBox[0] = picChair0;
arrPictureBox[1] = picChair1;
arrPictureBox[2] = picChair2;
arrPictureBox[3] = picChair3;
arrPictureBox[4] = picChair4;
arrPictureBox[5] = picChair5;
arrPictureBox[6] = picChair6;
arrPictureBox[7] = picChair7;
arrPictureBox[8] = picChair8;
arrPictureBox[9] = picChair9;
arrPictureBox[10] = picChair10;
arrPictureBox[11] = picChair11;
```

(pic) is a picturebox.

But I want less code but I don't know if it possible to do this with a loop (for loop).

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < arrPictureBox.Length; i++)
{
    arrPictureBox[i] = picChair + i;
}
```

Comment: how are you creating the picChair's ?

Comment: @LOLslowSTi If "picChairXX" are controls on a form that would be duplicate of one of many questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168363/c-sharp-create-an-array-of-controls (more can be found by search like https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+winform+array+controls)... So probably not controls but what?

Comment: Reflection via [Type.GetFields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getfields%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)? If you just want a concise notation, you could use `arrPictureBox = new[] {picChar0,picChair1,picChair2}`...

Comment: its funny how people are just assuming things and answering the question. There is clearly not enough information given here to produce a concise answer. With the information given, the only answer is `SomeType[] arrPictureBox = { picChair0, picChair1, picChair2, picChair3, picChair4, picChair5, picChair6, picChair7, picChair8, picChair9, picChair10, picChair11};`

Comment: i just wondering if it was possible to put the code above in a loop , the type of aplication that i made is a windows form , and the picChairx are picturboxes (controls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's predict you're on `WinForms` and the `pictureBoxes` already exist, then you can use the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrPictureBox.Length; i++)
{
    arrPictureBox[i] = this.Controls["picChair" + i];
}
```

Which actually does this:

- get the first `Control` (a `PictureBox` for example) with the given name
- add the found control to the array of pictureboxes

**EDIT:**

It might be useful to check for non existing `pictureBoxes`:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < arrPictureBox.Length; i++)
{
    var pb = this.Controls["picChair" + i] as PictureBox;
    if (pb != null)
    {
        arrPictureBox[i] = pb;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , that was what i mentioned .

Comment: @Sandeerius no problem, that's what `SO` is for :D

Answer (score 4):

If `picChairN` is a local variable then there's nothing you can do to simplify it as much as you'd like.  The best you can do is

```
arrPictureBox = new [] { picChair0, picChair1, picChair2, picChair3,
                         picChair4, picChair5, picChair6, picChair7, 
                         picChair8, picChair9, picChair10, picChair11};
```

If `picChairN` is a class member (e.g. a field created by the designer) then you *could* use reflection, but considering you *already* have the array method typed out I don't see much benefit.

Comment: It looks like `picChairN` is a form control (`PictureBox`). You could loop through all the controls to get all the pictureboxes that start with `picChair` and add it to a List (then ToArray if needed).

Comment: If it's windows form application isn't there a possibility to get all typeof(picturebox) from form object or something?

Comment: @RonBeyer true, but then you're putting your trust in the designer to name the controls properly and trust in the developer not to rename a control in a way that would break the logic.  It's _possible_ but I really don;t see what's wrong with adding 12 items to an array explicitly.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck sure (`Control.Controls`), but would you think OP asked question without researching possible options?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Yes there is, but neither of those details was stated in the question.  Plus you're trusting the `Controls` collection to have them in the right order (if order is important).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov like 50% of the questions here is done without research so i'd say yes

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Maybe a Carnac hat for "reading the mind of the OP"

Answer (score 0):

You can use al List like below.

```
  List<string> arrPictureBox = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            arrPictureBox.Add("picChair" + i);
        }
        var result = arrPictureBox.ToArray();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

If all the picture boxes are on the same form and are the ONLY picture boxes on the form, you can loop through them with something like the following:

```
int x = 0;
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
   if(c is PictureBox)
   {
     arrPictureBox[x++] = c
   }
}
```

Comment: And just how is arrPictureBox sized?  I did not vote you down.

Comment: you could make arrPictureBox by `new PictureBox[this.Controls.Count(c => c is PictureBox)]` but then you could just do   `this.Controls.Where(c => c is PictureBox).toArray(); `

Comment: My answer was meant as a quick example of how to loop through specific types of controls on a form, not a complete solution, on the assumption that this was being used on a Windows form (as the original poster later clarified) in his comments.  Not sure why that's worth a down vote to someone.  Just another Steve's solution is a more elegant way to do something similar but maybe a bit harder to understand for someone less experienced.